# How would I hide the new Windows 11 volume modal?

Tags: windows-11

Just received an update on Windows 11 (22612, but I'm not sure if that's the one that introduced the change) that changes the volume and brightness popups to now appear in the bottom center of the screen. I use ModernFlyouts and having the two popups on the screen at once is annoying, so I'm wonder if there is a way to hide the default Windows one completely.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I only get one Newest version of Windows 11. Can you edit your post with a screenshot of what you see?  Use Snipping tool as normally the best to capture this.